# Submit from external form, lost POST parameters

Tags: java, null, submit, wicket, post-parameter

I do a POST submit from a non-wicket page, but when I do:

```
IRequestParameters iRequestParameters = RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getPostParameters();
```

all the parameters are null

Why? how can it be possible?

This is my class that extends WebApplication:

public class CnsbApplication extends WebApplication {

```
public CnsbApplication() {
    // In case of unhandled exception redirect it to a custom page
    this.getRequestCycleListeners().add(new AbstractRequestCycleListener() {
        @Override
        public IRequestHandler onException(RequestCycle cycle, Exception e) {
            return new RenderPageRequestHandler(new PageProvider(
                    new ExceptionPage(e)));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public Class<? extends WebPage> getHomePage() {
    return EntryPage.class;
}

@Override
public void init() {
    super.init();
    // add your configuration here
    mountPackage("spages", it.CheckedPlafold.class);
    mountPage("/", EntryPage.class);
}

@Override
public Session newSession(Request request, Response response) {
    return new CnsbWebSession(request);
}
```

If I call my page without final slash (ex.    ...localhost/cnsb) my application cann't get post parameters, if I submit to ...localhost/cnsb/ all works

this is my form:

```
   <form action="http://localhost:8080/cnsbWeb/" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>id_tx_pagamento</td><td><input name="id_tx_pagamento" type="text" value="ASDFGHJLOR01234567891234567890123456"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>codice_fiscale_richiedente</td><td><input name="codice_fiscale_richiedente" type="text" value="MRNLGU76C07L736K"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>tipo_pagamento</td><td><input name="tipo_pagamento" type="text" value="CONTRATTO"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>id_chiamante</td><td><input name="id_chiamante" type="text" value="I_CMS"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>provider</td><td><input name="provider" type="text" value="ACTALIS"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>anno_richiesta</td><td><input name="anno_richiesta" type="text" value="2014"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>progressivo_richiesta</td><td><input name="progressivo_richiesta" type="text" value="7282920"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>sigla_provincia_emittente</td><td><input name="sigla_provincia_emittente" type="text" value="RO"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>codice_fiscale_titolare</td><td><input name="codice_fiscale_titolare" type="text" value="MRNLGU76C07L736K"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>numero_codici_prodotto</td><td><input name="numero_codici_prodotto" type="text" value="3"></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>codice_prodotto_1</td><td><input name="codice_prodotto_1" type="text" value="DKEYIWL21C11"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>codice_prodotto_2</td><td><input name="codice_prodotto_2" type="text" value="DKEYIWL22C11"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>codice_prodotto_3</td><td><input name="codice_prodotto_3" type="text" value="DKEYIWL22C11"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>quantita_1</td><td><input name="quantita_1" type="text" value="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>quantita_2</td><td><input name="quantita_2" type="text" value="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>quantita_3</td><td><input name="quantita_3" type="text" value="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sha1</td><td><input name="sha1" type="text" value="9a30412fdc3a7f9b04c86fee90960c1a9f5a7328"></td>
</tr>                                                   

</table>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

This is the initial code of EntryPage:

public EntryPage()  {
        LOGGER.debug("EntryPage");

```
    String userTitolareCNS = null;
    String cfUserEaco = null;
    String note= null;


    IRequestParameters iRequestParameters = RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getPostParameters();
```

iRequestParameters parameters are empty or full, depends how I call the url where I submit the form

Comment: We need to see a little more code.

Comment: Can you post your HTML too?

Comment: These code samples aren't helping. You've got methods mountPage() and mountPackage() but they're not in the class definition. Please post a minimal sample that demonstrates the problem. Help us to help you.